# multiple AJAX requests and multiple SetTimeout animations

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, ajax, animation

I wrote a piece of code that included multiple AJAX requests and multiple SetTimeout animations.

I want the code to perform better, **especially the SetTimeout sections.**

**which part of the code should be improved?**

```js
window.timer = [];
window.timerNum = 1;

function amLoading(timer) {
    var node = document.createElement("mark"),
        str = "Loading...",
        len = str.length,
        i = 0,
        html = "";

    node.classList.add("am-load");

    function typing() {
        console.log("timer > " + timer);

        if (i < len) {
            html += str[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            html = "";
            i = 0;
        }

        node.innerHTML = html;

        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            typing();
        }, 160);
    }

    typing();

    return node;
}

function requestData(option) {
    var list = option["list"],
        xhrType = option["type"],
        xhrUrl = option["src"],
        count = option["count"],
        num = window.timerNum++,
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        item = document.createElement("li");

    window.timer.push(num);
    // console.log(num);
    // console.log(window.timer[num-1]);
    var node = amLoading(window.timer[num - 1]);

    xhr.open("GET", xhrUrl, true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            if (node) {
                node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                clearTimeout(window.timer[num - 1]);
            }

            switch (xhrType) {
                case "json":
                    var par = document.createElement("p");
                    par.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                    item.appendChild(par);
                    break;
                case "image":
                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.src = xhrUrl;
                    item.appendChild(img);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            requestData.num++;
            // console.log(requestData.num);

            if (requestData.num === count) {
                list.classList.add("active");
            } else {
                list.classList.remove("active");
            }
        } else {
            item.appendChild(node);
        }

        list.appendChild(item);
    };

    xhr.send(null);
}

function renderData(option) {
    var wrapper = document.querySelector(option["selector"]),
        data = option["data"],
        requestCount = data.length;

    wrapper.innerHTML = "";

    if (data.length > 0) {
        data.forEach(function (value, index) {
            requestData.num = 0;

            requestData({
                "type": value["type"],
                "src": value["src"],
                "list": wrapper,
                "count": requestCount,
            });
        });
    }
}

var data = [{
        "type": "json",
        "src": "/data.json",
    },
    {
        "type": "image",
        // "src": "/github-logo.png-error",
        "src": "/github-logo.png",
    },
    {
        "type": "image",
        "src": "/node-logo.png",
    },
    {
        "type": "image",
        "src": "/python-logo.png",
    },
    {
        "type": "image",
        "src": "/vim-logo.png-error",
        // "src": "/vim-logo.png",
    },
    {
        "type": "image",
        "src": "/vscode-logo.png",
    },
];

renderData({
    "selector": ".list",
    "data": data,
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 1rem;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: #666;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

ol {
    letter-spacing: -8px;
}

ol>li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 1rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
}

ol>li>.am-load {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f80;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

ol.active>li {
    border-color: #fc8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Demo-AJAX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ol class="list"></ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give more context on what this code actually does (instead of just saying it uses multiple timers and XHR calls)?

Comment: Your code has bugs that you are aware of as you have  `console.log("timer > " + timer);` trying to track down why the timeouts are not cleared. (`amLoading(timer){` `timer` is a copy not a reference) It is also difficult to workout your intent (Why request the images then ignore the data when it has loaded? Why not create an Image and set its src without  the redundant fetch?) To get a good review you will need to fix your code and clarify your intent.

Comment: @Joseph This code can be executed normally, no bugs.
I want to write a JS component.

Comment: @Blindman67 This code can be executed normally. I want to write a JS component.